# Failed to install pidgin-whatsapp in Ubuntu 14.10 (Error - Failed to fetch PPA)

Tags: ppa, 14.10, pidgin, whatsapp

I am a new Ubuntu user. In the process of installing WhatsApp into Ubuntu 14.10, and while I have successfully installed Pidgin, I am facing problems when installing whatsapp-purple plugin for Pidgin.

When I ran:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:whatsapp-purple/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

I got this error message:

```
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/whatsapp-purple/ppa/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/whatsapp-purple/ppa/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

And then after running `sudo apt-get install pidgin-whatsapp` I got this error message:

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Unable to locate package pidgin-whatsapp
```

Do you have any suggestions for how to solve this?

Comment: Either the PPA repository has no packages for Utopic or no longer exist.